# Problems on converting tf2::Transform to geometry_msgs::msg::Transform

Tags: ros2, transform, tf2

I'm trying to convert `tf2::Transform` to `geometry_msgs::msg::Transform` with help of `tf2/convert.h` but I get compiler errors. I'm using ROS2 Humble with Ubuntu 22.04.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
    tf2::Transform transform;
    // make something with transform ...
    // Build a TransformStamped message
    geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped t;
    t.header.stamp = node->get_clock()->now();
    t.header.frame_id = frame_id;
    t.child_frame_id = child_frame_id;
    
    // Now try to assign the tf2::Transform to the transform in the message
    t.transform = tf2::toMsg<tf2::Transform, geometry_msgs::msg::Transform>(transform);
```

Error undefined reference to
geometry_msgs::msg::Transform_std::allocator<void > tf2::toMsg<tf2::Transform, geometry_msgs::msg::Transform_std::allocator<void > >(tf2::Transform const&)'

```
    // Another try with another function, this fails too
    tf2::convert(transform, t.transform)
```

Error /opt/ros/humble/include/tf2/tf2/impl/convert.h:67:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘toMsg(const tf2::Transform&)’
67 |   b = toMsg(a);

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!  Please edit and format your question correctly, such as adding errors on a separate snippet. There is no need to use a code style for writing regular text messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't figure out to use something from `tf2/convert.h`
I solved it now this way:

```
    geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped t;
    t.header.stamp = g_node->get_clock()->now();
    t.header.frame_id = frame_id;
    t.child_frame_id = child_frame_no;

    t.transform.translation.x = transform.getOrigin().getX();
    t.transform.translation.y = transform.getOrigin().getY();
    t.transform.translation.z = transform.getOrigin().getZ();

    t.transform.rotation.w = transform.getRotation().getW();
    t.transform.rotation.x = transform.getRotation().getAxis().getX();
    t.transform.rotation.y = transform.getRotation().getAxis().getY();
    t.transform.rotation.z = transform.getRotation().getAxis().getZ();

    br->sendTransform(t);
```